# TicTacToe where the computer plays random moves against itself

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a quick program in Python to play against itself in a game of (random) tic-tac-toe.

It seems to work, but can you guys please look at it and let me know if I'm doing things the 'correct' (i.e. idiomatic) and efficient way.

```
import random

#  Tic Tac Toe

#  Board is laid out as:
#  0, 1, 2,
#  3, 4, 5,
#  6, 7, 8

winning_rows = [
    [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],    # Horizontal
    [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],    # Vertical
    [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]                # Diagonal
    ]

def check_winner(board):
    for player in [1, 2]:
        for seq in winning_rows:
            for pos in seq:
                if (board[pos]!=player):
                    break
            else:
                return player

    #nobody won, check for draw (return 0 for draw, None for incomplete game)
    for pos in range(9):
        if (board[pos] == 0):
            return None

    #game is a draw
    return 0

def find_move(board, player):
    legal_moves = []

    for pos in range(9):
        if (board[pos] == 0):
            legal_moves.append(pos)

    return random.choice(legal_moves)

def make_move(board, move, player):
    board[move] = player

def write_board(board):
    #letter = {0: '-', 1: 'X', 2: 'O'}
    letter = "-XO"
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            print letter[board[row*3+col]], 
        print
    print

def play():
    board = []
    for pos in range(9):
        board.append(0)

    write_board(board)  

    player = 1
    while True:
        move = find_move(board, player)
        make_move(board, move, player)
        write_board(board)
        winner = check_winner(board)
        if winner != None:
            if winner == 1:
                print "Player 1 (X) wins!"
            if winner == 2:
                print "Player 2 (O) wins!"
            if winner == 0:
                print "Game is a draw!"
            break
        player = 3 - player

play()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Some of your functions can use list comprehensions.

  As you seem to know maths, you may have come across 'set-builder notation',
  and that's what list comprehension are based off:

  \$S = \{2 \times x | x \in \{0, 1, ..., 9\}, x^2 > 3\}\$

  Which in Python is:

  ```
  [2 * x for x in range(10) if x ** 2 > 3]
  ```

  I would use it in:

  - `find_move` for an improvement in clarity.

    ```
    def find_move(board, player):
        return random.choice([pos for pos in range(9) if board[pos] == 0])
    ```
  - `write_board` to use less `print`s. It's harder to read however.

    ```
    print '\n'.join([
        ''.join([letter[row + col] for col in range(3)])
        for row in range(0, 3, 9)
    ])
    ```
  - `check_winner` you can make your `for pos in seq` one.
    Using `all`.

    ```
    for player in [1, 2]:
        for seq in winning_rows:
            if all([board[pos] == player for pos in seq]):
                return player
    ```
  - I'm surprised you didn't make a `new_board` function. Which could be:

    ```
    def new_board():
        return [0 for _ in range(9)]
    ```

    Alternatively, as noted by @i-live-in-a-storm-drain, if you are ok with shallow copy's you could change it to:

    ```
    def new_board():
        return [0] * 9
    ```

    The down-side to this is if you mutate any of the items, then you mutate all of them. For example you wouldn't want to make a 2D list with it.

    ```
    >>> a = [[0] * 3] * 3
    >>> a[0][0] = 1
    >>> a
    [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
    ```
- Your function `make_move` seems, kinda pointless...
  I would use `board[move] = player` over the function.
- You should use `is` when comparing to singletons, `None`.

  ```
  # Bad
  if winner != None:

  # Good
  if winner is not None:
  ```
- You could make the win conditions a list, and print from that.

  ```
  win_statments = ["Player 1 (X) wins!", "Player 2 (O) wins!", "Game is a draw!"]
  print win_statments[winner]
  ```
- For `check_winner` you can use the fact `0 == False` (Not `0 is False`).
  With Python's builtin `all` to check if all of them are not 0.

  ```
  if not all(board):
      return None
  ```
- As this is Python2 it's recommended to use `xrange` rather than `range` for almost everything.
  You'll get a, minimal, speed increase in most situations.

  However as noted by @Janos, you could opt to keep them as `range`, for an easier transition to Python3. This is as there is no `xrange` in Python3.
  You should only need to change your prints to functions for this to work in Python3.

  ```
  # Change to these:
  print("Player 1 (X) wins!")

  # in `make_move`
  for col in range(3):
      print(letter[board[row*3+col]], end='')
  print()
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very detailed and I learned a lot about python!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman No problem, if you want something else to learn look into [generator comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension), they're like list comprehensions, but lazy.

Comment: Also instead of list comprehension for the board creation in `play` you could just use: `board = [0] * 9`

Answer (score 3):

`winning_rows` is a constant, so you should make it a tuple and put the name in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. Tuples are immutable, so this communicated the fact that it's a constant to the user.

```
WINNING_ROWS = (
    (0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8),    # Horizontal
    (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8),    # Vertical
    (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6)                # Diagonal
    )
```

In `check_winner` you could use `all` with a generator expression instead of having a nested loop. It's also clearer to read "if all board pos == player" as a success condition:

```
def check_winner(board):
    for player in [1, 2]:
        for seq in winning_rows:
            if all(board[pos] == player for pos in seq):
                return player
```

You could actually nest this even deeper with an `any` condition that iterates over all the winning row possibilities. This may be less readable, so it's up to you whether to adopt it or not:

```
    for player in [1, 2]:
        if any(all(board[pos] == player for pos in seq) 
               for seq in winning_rows):
            return player
```

To explain this tests if the `all` condition from above is `True` for `any` of the `seq`s in `winning_rows`.

Using `player = 3 - player` is a very confusing construct. You just need to iterate over player `1` and `2`, so just do that. In the `itertools` module there's a function called `cycle` that can endlessly loop over a sequence on repeat, so you can use that since you `break` when you need to anyway.

```
for player in itertools.cycle((1, 2)):
    move = find_move(board, player)
    make_move(board, move, player)
    write_board(board)
    winner = check_winner(board)
    if winner != None:
        if winner == 1:
            print "Player 1 (X) wins!"
        if winner == 2:
            print "Player 2 (O) wins!"
        if winner == 0:
            print "Game is a draw!"
        break
```

I would also prefer to `break` when `winner is not None` and handle the `print` outside the loop, like so:

```
for player in itertools.cycle((1, 2)):
    move = find_move(board, player)
    make_move(board, move, player)
    write_board(board)
    winner = check_winner(board)
    if winner is not None:
        break

if winner == 1:
    print "Player 1 (X) wins!"
elif winner == 2:
    print "Player 2 (O) wins!"
elif winner == 0:
    print "Game is a draw!"
```

In Python, a loop doesn't enclose a variable in local scope. This means that `winner` can be accessed from outside the loop. This means you can have less nesting and make it clearer what's happening in the control flow.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much!  Is there a performance improvement with using tuples or is it just a matter of keeping it constant and communicating so?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman There's a small difference, I don't think it will matter in your case and I mostly suggested it for style reasons. The performance difference is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python) but it mostly boils down to tuples are faster to build, while lists are slightly quicker to access.